# Find a band-pass filter

Tags: discrete-signals, finite-impulse-response, z-transform, bandpass, poles-zeros

The question is: how can I define $h_1[n]$ in such a way that $h [ n ] = \delta [n - 1 ] + 2 \delta [n -2 ] + h_ 1 [n]$ is a band-pass filter. My thought was the following.

Firstable, I wrote the $Z$-transform as $\displaystyle{H (z) = H_ 1 ( z) + z^ {-1} +2z^ {-2} = \frac{z^ 2 H_1 ( z) + z + 2 }{z ^ 2 }}$. Then I thought, since the sistem basically has two poles in 0, to add two poles, in $z = 1, -1 $ (in order to have the amplitude of $H( e^ {i\omega})$  vanishing for $\omega = 0, \pi $). I decided to take a signal of the form $h _1 [n] = A\delta [n + 1 ]+ B \delta [n+2 ] \implies H _1(z)  = A z + B {z ^2 } $ and I got, by the previous conditions, a system of equations:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
H ( -1 ) = H_1( -1 )+( -1)^ {-1} + 2  (-1  ) ^ 2  =  -A+  B +1= 0 \\
H (1) = H _1(1) +(1)^ {-1} +2(1 ) ^ 2  = A + B  +3 = 0 
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
so that $A= -1, B = -2 $. Therefore I concluded that  $h[n] =- \delta [n+1 ] - 2\delta [n+2] + \delta [n-1] + 2 \delta[n-2]$ is a band-pass filter. I draw the graph of the amplitude and it seems to be a kind of absolute value of a damping sinusoidal function (with zeros for $\omega = 0,  \omega _ 1, \pi $, where $\omega _ 1 $ is a value between $\frac \pi 2 $ and $ \frac 2 3 \pi  $).

I was wondering if my argument is correct. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to making this more complicated than it needs to be. If you want $h[n] = h_0[n] + h_1[n]$ to be a bandpass, than $h_1[n]$ is simply

$$h_1[n] = h[n] - h_0[n]$$

In other words: design any bandpass $h[n]$ you like, subtract 1 from the first coefficient and 2 from the second coefficient, and you have your $h_1[n]$